# Encountering a memory leak when recreating the swap chain in Vulkan

Tags: memory-leaks, game-engine, vulkan

I have been following a [Vulkan-tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/) and have noticed an issue when repeatedly minimizing the window. Since I'm working in Mircosoft Visual Studio, I am using the built in debugger and noticed the memory my application is using spikes by around 100MB every time I minimize and maximize the window. Since every time the window is minimized it triggers an error when acquiring the next image in the swap chain, I need to recreate it. Here's the code I'm describing:

```
    vkWaitForFences(_deviceManager.getDevice(), 1, &_inFlightFences[_currentFrame], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
    

    uint32_t imageIndex;

    VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(_deviceManager.getDevice(), _swapChainManager.getSwapChain(), UINT64_MAX,
        _imageAvailableSemaphores[_currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

    if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR) {
        _swapChainManager.recreateSwapChain(_windowManager.getWindow(), _deviceManager.getDevice(), 
            _physicalDeviceManager.getPhysicalDevice(), _surfaceManager.getSurface(), 
            _physicalDeviceManager.getMsaaSamples(), _renderPass);
        return;
    }
    else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
    }

    // Only reset the fence if we are submitting work
    vkResetFences(_deviceManager.getDevice(), 1, &_inFlightFences[_currentFrame]);
```

Basically, my function execute order is :

- vkWaitForFences(...)
- vkAcquireNextImageKHR(...)
- recreateSwapChain(...)
- vkResetFences(...)
  ...

And the code for recreating the swap chain is:

```
void SwapChainManager::recreateSwapChain(GLFWwindow* window, VkDevice device, VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, 
    VkSurfaceKHR surface, VkSampleCountFlagBits msaaSamples, VkRenderPass renderPass)
{
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
    while (width == 0 || height == 0) {
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        glfwWaitEvents();
    }

    vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);

    cleanupSwapChain(device);

    createSwapChain(window, physicalDevice, surface, device, msaaSamples);
    createImageViews(device);

    colorResources.createResources(_swapChainExtent.width, _swapChainExtent.height,
        _swapChainImageFormat, physicalDevice, msaaSamples, device);

    depthResources.createResources(_swapChainExtent.width, _swapChainExtent.height,
        physicalDevice, msaaSamples, device);

    createFramebuffers(device, renderPass);

}
```

Mind the messy code. The function cleanupSwapchain() just destroys and frees memory held by the swapchain.

I've noticed a similar issue was raised in this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/amabvq/vkcreateswapchainkhr_memory_leak/) and the last comment raised that querying for device properties should only be ran once, not every time you recreate the swap chain. I wrapped it in an std::optional and asking for device properties only when it doesn't hold anything. This didn't fix the issue.

Furthermore when I exit the application, the console alerts me that I'm not destroying VkImages and VkImageView before destroying the VkDevice (also some VkDeviceMemory and a VkBuffer, but this might be a separate issue).

I'm new to the Vulkan API, so if I didn't supply enough code, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: What does cleanupSwapChain() do?

Comment: Also, have you run with the validation layers enabled? They normally give more feedback with specific object handles which can help you track them down.

Comment: Hey @solidpixel, thanks for replying! the cleanupswapchain function destroys and frees the depth and color resources, as well as the framebuffers, imageviews as well as the swap chain itself. The only validation layer I have enabled is VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation, which is why I was able to catch the memory not being freed when I was destroying the device.

Comment: I just made my [github repository] (https://github.com/CalebDerrickson/VulkanTest/tree/feature/ClassPartition/) for it public. I linked the classPartition branch since this is the one I've been working on. I've been trying to separate every module into manager classes - I'm in the middle of doing that and the latest is the swapchain. I also have an issue set up for it.